# celery cant find static files in django app during development

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

My django web app loads static files no problem in DEBUG mode with the magic of `django.contrib.staticfiles`.

However, my celery service can't find the files!  This makes sense, because [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/) say that `django.contrib.staticfiles` works automagically when `runserver` command is used, but celery doesn't use the `runserver` command, so how do I get celery to access those files in development?

Here is how one of my models gets an static image to use as a default icon:

```
from django.templatetags.static import static

    some_method():
        return static('img/default_icon.png')
```

But with the same code run by celery, celery can't find the image.  Celery says it's looking for the image at "/static/img/default_icon.png" which makes sense because my django settings has:

`STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Comment: Why does celery need static files? What is it doing with them?

Comment: Sending notification emails with a logo/icon

Comment: You'll need to show the code that tries to access them. How are you inserting the icons into the email?

Comment: added to OP....

Answer (score 0):

Are you using docker, docker-compose or something like that?
If it is, you need to add static volume to your docker container in `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the exact same problem.